# How to extract the baseline hazard function h0(t) from glmnet object in R?

Tags: r, glmnet, cox-regression, hazard

## Extract the baseline hazard function h0(t) from glmnet object

I want to know the hazard function at time t >> h(t,X) = h0(t) exp[Σ βi*Xi]. How can I extract the baseline hazard function h0(t) from glmnet object in R?

What I know is that function "basehaz()" in Survival Packages can extract the baseline hazard function from coxph object only.

I also found a function,  `glmnet.basesurv(time, event, lp, times.eval = NULL, centered = FALSE)`. But when I try to use this function, there is an error.

> Error: could not find function "glmnet.basesurv"

Below is my code, using glmnet to fit the cox model and obtained the coefficients of selected variables. Is it possible to get the baseline hazard function h0(t) from this glmnet object?

## Code

```
    # Split data into training data and testing data 
    set.seed(101) 
    train_ratio = 2/3
    sample <- sample.int(nrow(x), floor(train_ratio*nrow(x)), replace = F)
    x.train <- x[sample, ]
    x.test <- x[-sample, ]
    y.train <- y[sample, ]
    y.test <- y[-sample, ]

    surv_obj <- Surv(y.train[,1],y.train[,2]) 

    # 
    my_alpha = 0.5

    fit = glmnet(x = x.train, y = surv_obj, family = "cox",alpha = my_alpha)  # fit the model with elastic net method
    plot(fit,xvar="lambda", main="cox model coefficient paths(glmnet.fit)\n\n") # Plot the paths for the fit
    fit 

    # cross validation to find out best lambda
    cv_fit = cv.glmnet(x = x.train,y = surv_obj , family = "cox",nfolds = 10,alpha = my_alpha) 

    tencrossfit <- cv_fit$glmnet.fit 
    plot(cv_fit, main="Cross-validated Deviance(10 folds cv.glmnet.fit)\n\n") 

    plot(tencrossfit, main="cox model coefficient paths(10 folds cv.glmnet.fit)\n\n")

    max(cv_fit$cvm)
    summary(cv_fit$cvm)
    cv_fit$lambda.min
    cv_fit$lambda.1se

    coef.min = coef(cv_fit, s = "lambda.1se")

    pred_min_value2 <- predict(cv_fit, s=cv_fit$lambda.min, newx=x.test,type="link")
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The `glmnet.basesurv` function is part of the hdnom package (which is available on CRAN), not glmnet itself. So install that, and then call it.

Comment: Thanks. I installed hdnom packages, but still not working. 

glmnet.basesurv(time, event, pred_min_value2 , times.eval = 30, centered = FALSE)
Error: could not find function "glmnet.basesurv"
Any other packages I need to install? 

It is weird that I can find function glmnet.basesurv from this webpage(https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hdnom/versions/4.6).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar question and after installing hdnom `install.packages("hdnom")`, if you check inside the function list  `library(help = "hdnom")`
you can see that the function is actually `glmnet_survcurve()`. I made it working as `hdnom:::glmnet_survcurve()`, example is here:

```
S <- Surv(data$survtimed, data$outcome)
X_glm<-model.matrix(S~.,data[, c("factor1", "factor2")])
cox_model <- glmnet(X_glm, S, family="cox", alpha=1, lambda=0.2)
times = c (1,2) #for predict of survival and 
linearpredictors at times = 1 and 2
predictions = hdnom:::glmnet_survcurve(cox_model, S[,1], S[,2], X_glm, survtime = times)
predictions$p[,1] #survival probability at time 1
```